# Uniqueness of function approximation over three points?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, approximation-theory

Given a function $f(x)$, we want to approximate $f$ using $P(x)$, such that:
$P(x_0) = f(x_0)$, $P(x_2) = f(x_2)$, $P'(x_1) = f'(x_1)$. Prove that such a $P$ is unique $\iff$ $x_1 \neq \frac{1}{2}(x_0+x_2)$. I have no idea where to start with this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "Approximate" or "interpolate"? – And I don't think this makes sense without some restrictions on what $P$ is (such as a polynomial of some maximal degree).

Comment: Yes, I guess the meaning would be "intrepolate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement is wrong without any further restrictions, because if
$P$ satisfies
$$
 P(x_0) = f(x_0) \, , \quad P(x_2) = f(x_2) \,, \quad P'(x_1) = f'(x_1)
\tag 1
$$
then for any differentiable function $g$
$$
  \tilde P(x) = P(x) + g(x)(x-x_0)(x-x_1)^2(x-x_2)
$$
satisfies $(1)$ as well.

---

What you are probably looking for are *quadratic polynomials*
$$
 P(x) = a x^2 + b x + c
$$
satisfying the interpolation conditions $(1)$. Then
$$ \begin{aligned}
  a x_0^2 + b x_0 + c &= f(x_0) \\
  a x_2^2 + b x_2 + c &= f(x_2) \\
  2 a x_1 + b &= f'(x_1)
\end{aligned}
$$
must hold. This is a linear system of 3 equations for the 3 variables
$a, b, c$. It is well-known that the system has a *unique* solution
if and only if the *determinant* of the coefficients
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
x_0^2 & x_0 & 1 \\
x_2^2 & x_2 & 1 \\
2x_1 & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}
$$
is not zero (and no or many solutions otherwise, depending on the
values on the right-hand side of the equations).

This should lead you to the intended condition 
$x_1 \neq \frac{1}{2}(x_0+x_2)$ .

---

A different way to look at it is the following: If both $P_1$ and
$P_2$ are quadratic polynomials satisfying $(1)$, then
$Q := P_1 - P_2$ is a polynomial of degree at most 2 and satisfies

$$
 Q(x_0) = Q(x_2) = Q'(x_1) = 0 \, .
$$
On the other hand, the vertex (or turning point) of a quadratic
function is in the middle between the zeros, so that
$$
Q'(\frac {x_0 + x_2}{2}) = 0\, .
$$
It follows that $Q \equiv 0$ or $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}(x_0+x_2)$.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great explanation!

Comment: @ChrisW: You are welcome! (I have added another more geometric argument.)